# SmartImageView url loading

Tags: java, android, image, url

So I'm trying to get this image to load from a URL using the smart image view jar but I can't seem to get it to show up on the app. 
I have this in my .xml file:

```
  <com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
android:id="@+id/my_image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and this in my .java file:

```
SmartImageView myImage = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    myImage.setImageUrl("https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0c8gk27sk23s7e/aloe.png");
```

There is no errors or anything wrong with the code. It just doesn't show the pic in the app. Am I using the wrong URL or am I placing it in the wrong place in my code? the java code is right after the oncreate method and the xml code is within the layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct link to an image. In fact this opens a webpage where you can view the image and optionally download it.

If you want to get a direct download link from dropbox, you'd probably have to use their APIs (which I am not familiar with).

Comment: So, what is a recommended way to get a link to an image? Is there a different online cloud service that would get me the link to an image easier?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Simply get a link for pictures that I took my self so that I can put them in my app. Thats why I used dropbox because I could upload my pics there and I thought that the link would work. So do you know any website or method to getting a URL for a pic that I personally took?

Comment: There are a lot of services which provide image hosting with direct linking. Here's a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+image+hosting+with+direct+linking).

Answer (score 0):

https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AABmUjwVdIrYYAEOXCSfNCvou9s39GAlH-hkfhp8tu9iKQ/12/108949633/png/1024x768/3/1431327600/0/2/aloe.png/CIHh-TMgASACIAMgBCAFKAE/0djAIzvqFJ2KNVfH1r80zH7gz6RMd9XEFvyCBTQmgRk

here's the really pic link from ur link ...

"https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0c8gk27sk23s7e/aloe.png"

```
<div class="preview-box" style="width: 373px;">
<img src="https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AABmUjwVdIrYYAEOXCSfNCvou9s39GAlH-hkfhp8tu9iKQ/12/108949633/png/1024x768/3/1431327600/0/2/aloe.png/CIHh-TMgASACIAMgBCAFKAE/0djAIzvqFJ2KNVfH1r80zH7gz6RMd9XEFvyCBTQmgRk" alt="" id="preview-img" class="content-shadow cpyxl5336459480969261158" data-original-href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0c8gk27sk23s7e/aloe.png?dl=1" enable-download="true"/>
...
</div>
```

Comment: just "preview" version